# Tab Across to an IE Tab using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, hyperlink, tabs

I have VBA code that launches a webpage, searches for a hyperlink, clicks the hyperlink to open another IE tab that asks what version of Excel to view that data in.

> Please select version of Excel
>   (o) Excel 2000
>   (o) Previous versions
>
> Ok Cancel

But I can not set focus to the newly created IE Tab after having clicked the hyperlink from the initial page.

The code below so far works well.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim winShell As Shell
Dim ie As Object
Dim ie_window As Variant
Dim target_URL As String

Dim ieApp As Object
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieForm As Object
Dim ieObj As Object
Dim lnk

target_URL = Worksheets("Control Panel").Range("B3").Value
no_of_tabs_to_hit = Worksheets("Control Panel").Range("B5").Value
                                        With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    If .Count > 0 Then
        Set ie = .Item(0) '.Item(.Count + 1)        ' Get IE
    Else
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")   ' Create IE
        ie.Visible = True
    End If
    ie.Navigate target_URL
    ie.Visible = True
End With

ie.Visible = True

'----------------------- WAIT FOR IE TO CATCH UP ----------------------------
newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 4
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
Application.Wait waitTime
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set winShell = New Shell          'loop through the windows and look at the urls
For Each ie In winShell.Windows
    If InStr(1, ie.LocationURL, "PT2200JC", vbString) > 0 Then
        ie.Visible = True 'GetInternetWindow = ie
        'AppActivate ie
        Exit For
    End If
Next
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Set doc = ie.Document
For Each lnk In doc.Links
    If InStr(1, lnk.innerHTML, "View&nbsp;in&nbsp;Excel", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Links on page are : " & lnk.innerHTML
        lnk.Click
    End If
Next lnk

'Application.SendKeys "^~"               ' 22

'Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your I used the above to get to the correct page and I managed to find far better way to click the hyperlink.

```
Set doc = ie.Document
For Each lnk In doc.Links
    If InStr(1, lnk.innerHTML, "View&nbsp;in&nbsp;Excel", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Links on page are : " & lnk.innerHTML
        lnk.Click
    End If
Next lnk
```

Thanks very much Kuldip.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you identify and focus on the desired web page

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

 'find the desired page
    If my_title Like "Put something from your IE page title here" & "*" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next
```