# How is it possible to click on a button present in a newly opened tab in internet explorer using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Here is the code I wrote.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Press_Button()

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls (shdocvw.dll)
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim the_input_elements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim input_element As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim IeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim IeDoc2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim input_element2 As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim the_input_elements2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With objIE
    .Navigate "https://www.ndexsystems.com/fengine/fullservice/en/kerrfinancialsalogin.go?fromLogoff=true" ' Main page

    .Visible = 1
    Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    'PART 1: set user name and password
    Set htmlDoc = .document
    Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
    Do While htmlDoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
    For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
       If htmlInput.Name = "textbox_password" Then
            htmlInput.Value = "***"
        Else
            If htmlInput.Name = "textbox_id" Then
                htmlInput.Value = "***"
            End If
        End If
    Next htmlInput

    'PART 2: click login
    Set htmlDoc = .document
    Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    Do While htmlDoc.readyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
    For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
        If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" Then
            htmlInput.Click
            Exit For
        End If
   Next htmlInput

   'PART 3: Clicks on portfolio management button 
   Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
   Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
            Set IeDoc = .document
            Set the_input_elements = IeDoc.getElementsByClassName("big_button")
            For Each input_element In the_input_elements
                If input_element.href = "javascript:changePageToFrontdoor(false);" Then
                    input_element.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next input_element

    'PART 4: Clicks on the 'Advanced search' button
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
    Set IeDoc2 = .document
    Set the_input_elements2 = IeDoc2.getElementsByClassName("parent-item")
    For Each input_element2 In the_input_elements2
    If input_element2.href = "javascript:directToSearch()" Then
    input_element2.Click
    Exit For
    End If
    Next input_element2



End With

End Sub
```

Parts 1, 2 and 3 work perfectly. When I run this macro, it is actually logging in the website with my credentials. In part 3, it is also clicking on the button called "Porfolio management". 
However, by clicking on the "portfolio management" button, a new tab is opened with another page of the same website. 
On this newly opened page, there is a button called "Advanced search" that I want to click. Here is the HTML code of the button. [image]

Part 4 is not working with this code. It is not giving me any error, it is just not doing anything. I don't know where my error is because I wrote part 4 with the exact same syntax as part 3 and it is only part 3 that is actually running and giving the correct result (clicking on the button).

Maybe the fact that part 3 opens a new tab of this website should imply an additional step that I didn't do in step 4? Since I am not working with the same tab anymore...

Can anyone help me with finding the error?

Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21050966/8769365

Comment: @Nacorid i tried adding the code in the link you sent me. Thank you for your feedback but it did not change anything in the results of running the macro

Comment: When stepping through your code have you confirmed that `input_element2` is capturing the correct element? It's possible that your if statement never returns `True` and therefore it never fires the click event.

Comment: @RobertTodar Thank you for your feedback! Actually, while debugging, when the code reaches the line "For Each input_element2 in the_input_elements2" in the Part4 code, it actually jumps directly to the "End With" without entering the if statement and actually looping through all the elements. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I would just step through the code and see where the breakdown is. Start from ` Set IeDoc2 = .document ` and make sure it is capturing the correct document. If so, then check that `.getElementsByClassName("parent-item")` is actually returning elements (which it sounds like it isn't).

Comment: Also, note that long procedures like this should really be broken up into smaller methods so it's easier to read, debug, reuse, and refactor as you need. Here is a helpful [rubberduck blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/clean-vba-code-pt-1-bad-habits/) about writing clean code. I'm also starting to work on a [style guide](https://github.com/todar/VBA) to help write clean VBA.

Comment: @RobertTodar how can i verify if it is capturing the correct document? Thank you for your help i will also look into the links you sent me

Comment: Look at your locals window, and it's really up to you how you want to verify it is the correct document. You could use the `location.href` or `.Body.innerHTML` for examples.

Comment: From the part 4 code, I can see that you had assigned the same .document object to IeDoc2. So looks like you are still referring to the login page. That's why your code not able to find that element. After login to the site you can again try to use objIE.Navigate to navigate to new page and than try to find and click the button may help to solve the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT how is it possible to always refer to the newly opened page? I don't know the URL at the begining because it varies everytime you open the websit
For example: https://www.***.com/fengine/microsoft_browser/fullservice/brokerhomepage.do?X-CSRF-TOKEN=cf73f0665c9b7decfb185fd8e15a31a4

Comment: @CelineN, Please check the answer it may help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is different every time and you are not available with that URL than you can try to refer steps below.

(1) create object of Shell application.

(2) Than try to count IE windows and loop through it.

(3) After that match the **page title** with all the tabs and find the desired tab and assigned it to IE object and than you can try to interact with that page.

Example:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

 'find the desired page
    If my_title Like "Put something from your IE page title here" & "*" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next
```

You can modify the above code based on your requirement.

For more information, you can refer link below.

[VBA-Excel: Get ALL The Opened Internet Explorer (IE) using Microsoft Excel](https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-get-all-the-opened-internet-explorer-ie-using-microsoft-excel/)